# adding values in list with user defined class

Tags: java, android

i am new to andoird and i am using list with custom defined class but i am not sure how to add my key value pair in this list
here is my code

```
public class Pair<K,V> {
    private K k;
    private V v;

    public Pair(K k,V v)
    {
        this.k=k;
        this.v=v;

    }
    public K getK()
    {
        return k;
    }

    public void setK( K k)
    {
        this.k=k;
    }

    public V getV()
    {
        return v;
    }
    public void setV(V v)
    {
        this.v=v;
    }
}
```

and

```
List<Pair<String,String>> pl = new ArrayList<Pair<String,String>>();
```

I tried

```
pl.add(Pair("name","ahsen"));
 pl.addAll(Pair("name","ahsen"));
```

but its not working

Comment: `pl.add(new Pair<String, String>("name","ahsen"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

am i missing something or its just missing **new** operator ?

```
pl.add(new Pair("name","ahsen"));
pl.addAll(new Pair("name","ahsen"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `new` operator.

```
pl.add(new Pair("name","ahsen"));
```

You can use a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html) for key/value pairs.